# jquery-confirm confirmation popup disapearance problem

Tags: javascript, laravel, popup

I have a list of employees and each has a delete operation button and i am using jquery-confirm.js
library but when i click delete button confirmation popup appears and immediately disappears after a few seconds without clicking any button.
here is the js code of the pop up

```
  $('.deleteBtn').on('click',function () {
    $.alert({
        title: 'تایید حذف',
        content: 'آیا میخواهید این کارمند حذف شود؟',
        rtl: true,
        closeAnimation: 'scale',
        useBootstrap:true,
        closeIcon: true,
        buttons: {
            confirm: {
                text: 'تایید',
                btnClass: 'btn-blue',
                action: function () {
                    $.alert('تایید شد.');
                }
            },
            cancel: {
                text: 'انصراف',
                action: function () {
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

and here is the delete button:

```
<td><a href="{{route('employee.delete',$employee->id)}}" class="deleteBtn"><i class="icon-trash"></i></a></td>
```

Comment: I've just tested it, It stays, no disappearing problem.
Is there any other JavaScript code on your page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click on this button it goes to that route and refreshes the page, you should use ajax like below
change your button to:

```
<a id="{{$employee->id)}}" class="deleteBtn"><i class="icon-trash"></i></a>
```

and your `js` code:

```
$('.deleteBtn').on('click',function () {

let id = $(this).attr('id');
$.alert({
    title: 'تایید حذف',
    content: 'آیا میخواهید این کارمند حذف شود؟',
    rtl: true,
    closeAnimation: 'scale',
    useBootstrap:true,
    closeIcon: true,
    buttons: {
        confirm: {
            text: 'تایید',
            btnClass: 'btn-blue',
            action: function () {
              
            $.ajax({
                type: "get",
                url: "{{route('employees.delete')}}",
                data: {
                    'id': id
                },
                success: function (msg) {
                    alert('انجام شد!')

                   
                }
            });
            }
        },
        cancel: {
            text: 'انصراف',
            action: function () {
            }
        }
    }
});
```